# Join multiple rows with specific delimiter to one row

Tags: perl, shell, awk, sed, tr

I want to join multiple rows in that case there always 4 after the delimiter, but that doesn't mean in the future one of then can be with more of 4 rows. Anyway I want to join them in one row when use that delimiter `--` and to exclude him from the final view example:

```
--
        CATALOG
        DB1
        1
         good
--
        USERS
        DB2
        3
         good
```

I try several things with `tr` also `awk` without success.

The final view which I want to make is:

```
CATALOG DB1 1 good
USERS DB2 3 good
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set the record separator to `--` and then loop through the fields:

```
awk -v RS="--" 'NF{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf ("%s%s", $i, (i==NF?"\n":FS) )}' file
```

#### Explanation

- `-v RS="--"` set record separator to `--` instead of the default new line
- `NF{}` whenever there are fields in the record, do what is inside the brackets.
- `for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf ("%s%s", $i, (i==NF?"\n":FS) )` loop through the fields printing all of them. The separator between them is always `FS` (its default value is a space) and a new line if we are processing the last one.

#### Test

With extra lines.

```
$ cat a
--
        CATALOG
        DB1
        1
         good
--
        USERS
        DB2
        3
         good
    bad
$ awk -v RS="--" 'NF{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf ("%s%s", $i, (i==NF?"\n":FS) )}' a
CATALOG DB1 1 good
USERS DB2 3 good bad
```

Comment: You need `gnu awk` for this, due to multiple characters in Record Selector.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '#n
/^--$/ b print
H;$!b
:print
s/.*//;x;s/^[[:cntrl:][:space:]]*//;s/[[:cntrl:][:space:]]\{1,\}/ /gp' YourFile
```

- remove line starting with -- and print buffer content if occur (so last section)
- load in buffer current line
- if not end of file cycle
- print content (so end or new section) after reformat by removing space and new lines

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple `gnu awk` (gnu due to multiple characters in RS).

```
awk -v RS="--" '{$1=$1}NR>1' file
CATALOG DB1 1 good
USERS DB2 3 good
```

`$1=$1` this recreate the file with the new Record Selector, and uses default field space.
`NR>1` Then print all line except the first one (blank).